# Calculate total user engagement on mobile

Tags: sql, algorithm, apache-spark-sql, snowplow

I want to calculate the total user engagement (session duration) done by a user in a particular mobile session. We also have events from mobile to track if a user background or foreground the app. The background and foreground events are tracked when the user moves the app to background (the app goes off screen) and foreground (the app becomes visible on the screen again).

Session Table:

| Description (not part of table) | event_name | collector_tstamp | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Background the app | application_background | 2023-12-05T06:18:42.202+0000 | A |
| Browsing | screen_view | 2023-12-05T06:18:32.097+0000 | A |
| Foreground the app | application_foreground | 2023-12-05T06:18:31.955+0000 | A |
| Background the app | application_background | 2023-12-05T05:40:28.096+0000 | A |
| Browsing | screen_view | 2023-12-05T05:40:25.097+0000 | A |
| Browsing | screen_view | 2023-12-05T05:40:23.097+0000 | A |
| Open the app | open_the_app | 2023-12-05T05:40:22.000+0000 | A |

Expected output:

| session_id | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| A | 17 seconds |

Explanation:
The time between first time background the app from the open the app is 6 seconds (2023-12-05T05:40:28.096+0000 minus 2023-12-05T05:40:22.000+0000).
The time between subsequent background the app from the last foreground the app is 11 seconds (2023-12-05T06:18:42.202+0000 minus 2023-12-05T06:18:31.955+0000). so 6 + 11 = 17 seconds.
And so on.

I want to write sql query to calculate session duration. Any sql language will work, I just want to understand the logic.

Comment: Please choose a single database engine, MySQL is not SQL Server. Also what does this have to do with pyspark?

Comment: It is like any language will work for me. I just want to understand the solution logic.

Comment: The solution is likely to be specific to the functionality that your DBMS provides - hence the need for you to tag your question with the actual DBMS you are using

Comment: Okay, I would prefer answer in spark sql

Comment: Your math is wrong, 05:24:27.096 - 05:18:22.000 is actually 365.096 seconds. Its 6 minutes, not 6 seconds. The second block is 10.247 seconds, so a total of 375.343 seconds... If you are using the numbers to explain your logic, you really should get these details right

Comment: If you want to learn about this type of logic, lookup _Gap and Island analysis_ in your preferred language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20418616/rob-eyre) and [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13658399/nickw), I refer and combine them and created the below:

```
WITH time_idle AS (
    SELECT
    sessionid,
    SUM(datediff(
        second,
        prev_timestamp,
        collector_tstamp)
    ) as time_idle_duration
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
          sessionid,
          event_name,
          collector_tstamp,
          LAG(event_name) OVER (ORDER BY collector_tstamp) AS prev_event,
          LAG(collector_tstamp) OVER (ORDER BY collector_tstamp) AS prev_timestamp
      FROM EVENTS
      WHERE event_name IN ('application_foreground', 'application_background')
    )
    WHERE event_name = 'application_foreground' and prev_event = 'application_background'
    group by sessionid
)
select
    DISTINCT
    sce.sessionid,
    datediff(
        second,
        MIN(sce.collector_tstamp) OVER (PARTITION BY sce.sessionid),
        MAX(sce.collector_tstamp) OVER (PARTITION BY sce.sessionid)
        )
    - ti.time_idle_duration as total_duration,
    datediff(
        second,
        MIN(sce.collector_tstamp) OVER (PARTITION BY sce.sessionid),
        MAX(sce.collector_tstamp) OVER (PARTITION BY sce.sessionid)
        ) AS absolute_time_duration,
      ti.time_idle_duration
from EVENTS sce
JOIN time_idle ti on sce.sessionid = ti.sessionid
```

I am just calculating total down time by a user on a session, and subtract with  total duration of a session.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're grouping by session_id, and your timestamp can be cast to a numeric value (eg to a unix timestamp), you could break this down like this:

Total time elapsed in session:

```
MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(collector_tstamp))
- MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(collector_tstamp))
```

From this you could substract the 'downtime' - the intervals between background and foreground events:

```
SUM(IF(
    event_name = 'application_foreground',
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(collector_tstamp), 0
))
- SUM(IF(
      event_name = 'application_background'
      AND collector_tstamp < (
          SELECT MAX(s.collector_tstamp)
          FROM session s
          WHERE s.session_id = session.session_id
          AND event_name = 'application_foreground'
      ), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(collector_tstamp), 0
))
```

Putting it all together:

```
SELECT
    session_id,
    (
        MAX(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(collector_tstamp))
      - MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(collector_tstamp))
    )
    - (
        SUM(IF(
            event_name = 'application_foreground',
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(collector_tstamp), 0
        ))
        - SUM(IF(
            event_name = 'application_background'
            AND collector_tstamp < (
                SELECT MAX(s.collector_tstamp)
                FROM session s
                WHERE s.session_id = session.session_id
                AND event_name = 'application_foreground'
            ), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(collector_tstamp), 0
        ))
    ) AS duration
FROM session
GROUP BY session_id
```

NB this answer prepared for a MySQL server - you may have to adapt for other SQL engines.

Comment: Thank You Rob, I uses your logic to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want. You could combine some/all of the CTEs into a single step but I have left them there so that the logic is clear:

```
with relevant_events as ( -- not all events are required for the calculation
    select *
    from session_events
    where event_name in ('open_the_app', 'application_background', 'application_foreground')
),
prev_ts as ( -- get the timestamp of the previous event
    select 
    session_id
    ,event_name
    ,collector_tstamp
    ,lag(collector_tstamp) over (partition by session_id order by collector_tstamp asc) prev_tstamp
    from relevant_events
),
elapsed_time as ( -- calculate the time between the event and the previous event
    select 
    session_id
    ,event_name
    ,collector_tstamp
    ,prev_tstamp
    ,round(TIMESTAMPDIFF('ms',prev_tstamp , collector_tstamp)/1000,3) duration
    from prev_ts
)
-- We only need the elapsed time when the application_background event happens
select session_id, sum(duration)
from elapsed_time
where event_name = 'application_background'
group by session_id
;
```

Comment: Thank You Nick, I was able to solve the problem using yours and Rob's logic